# Could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift5

This is driving me insane. I've put together dozens of collections views in the past, but this one is refusing to work.

I have a xib for my collection view cell, and I gave it an identifier, "My Cell". In my controller, I do the following:

```
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        myCollectionView.delegate = self
        myCollectionView.dataSource = self

        // Register the collection view cell
        myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? MyCell else {
                fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MyCell.")
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Yet no matter what I do, Xcode is crashing and giving me this error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I've tried cleaning the build folder, restarting Xcode, even restarting my Mac, and nothing works.

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Add the `cellForItem` code as well please and also check if the `UINib` is getting loaded

Comment: @Rikh Updated the question

Comment: This code is in a ViewController ?

Comment: @King.lbt It's in a UIView custom class

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are providing the same exact identifier. `Copy/Paste` to make sure they are the same.

Comment: Yep, it's the exact same.

Comment: Is the xib added to your project target?

Comment: Seems to be, yes

Comment: try printing out `UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)` and see what you get?

Comment: I get `<UINib: 0x600003a040c0>`

Comment: @user93489112 Is the `awakeFromNib` method getting called?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check two things

1. use this  myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell

   `
   override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()

   ```
       myCollectionView.delegate = self
       myCollectionView.dataSource = self

       // Register the collection view cell
       myCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       guard let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? MyCell else {
               fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MyCell.")
       }

       return cell
   }`
   ```
2. Open Xib file and check whether reusable identifier is set or not

[image]

Hope this will solve your issue , if not let me know